Autodesk Webhooks not supporting multiple callback filters
I'm trying to create a webhook for the dm.verison.modified event, but want to filter it down to events that are for file extension .rvt and the storm:process-state equal to PROCESSING_COMPLETE. This way I only receive callback from webhook when a Revit file is done processing on ACC. Ref the blog post that shows how we can track process state of a file using Webhook responses: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/parse-webhook-response-modified-event-different-file-types.
I see that Webhooks API supports callback filtering with multiple filters:https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/developers_guide/callback-filtering/
But I am unable to create a webhook with multiple filters. I get a 400 Bad Request when my request contains an array of filters. Here is my request:
POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/webhooks/v1/systems/data/events/dm.version.added/hooks
Body:
{
    "callbackUrl": "https://my-app.com/webhooks/callback/version-modified",
    "scope": {
        "folder": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:xxxxxxx"
    },
    "filter": ["$[?(@.ext=='rvt')]", "$[?(@.custom-metadata.storm:process-state=='NEEDS_PROCESSING')]"]
}

The response I get from Webhook API:
{
    "id": "866d6804-5c42-4c26-bf54-4e72be2bff7a",
    "status": 400,
    "code": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "detail": [
        "Payload is not valid for serialization"
    ]
}

I have tried multiple variations of passing the whole array of filters as a single string literal, like so: "[$[?(@.ext=='rvt')], $[?(@.custom-metadata.storm:process-state=='NEEDS_PROCESSING')]]".
But I still get a 400 Bad Request, with the error " Invalid filter: [$[?(@.ext=='rvt')], $[?(@.custom-metadata.storm:process-state=='NEEDS_PROCESSING')]]"

The Callback Filtering documentation you provided the link to refers to the JsonPath format that the filter requires.
The readme there says:

Based on that I could come up with this that was accepted when creating the webhook:
$[?(@.ext=='rvt' || @.custom-metadata.storm:process-state=='NEEDS_PROCESSING')]

Update:
I was told that this should work (notice there is no space after the comma, otherwise it won't be accepted):
"filter": "[\"$[?(@.ext=='rvt')]\",\"$[?(@.custom-metadata.storm:process-state=='NEEDS_PROCESSING')]\"]",


Thanks, I ultimately did use that syntax from JSONPath, but the documentation provided by Autodesk still stands to be incorrect.  They've mentioned multiple filters can be passed in as a JSON array  [“$[?(@.sizeInBytes>=1048576)]”,”$[?(@.ext==’f3d’)]”], but this is rejected by Webhooks API as invalid format for filter field.

I reached out to the team to get the documentation fixed
